# Problem with multicolumn table !Misplaced \omit.\multispan -> \omit\omit\@multispan

Tags: longtable, multicolumn

I'm trying to make a table with multicolumns, in order to get something like this:[image]

But when I compile I get this error and can't figure out why:

!Misplaced \omit.\multispan -> \omit\omit@multispan multicolumn{4}{c}{\textbf{Jamiltepec}}

Here is my MWE:

```
\documentclass[10pt,cleardoublepage=empty,twoside]{book}
\usepackage[a5paper]{geometry}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc} 
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{lscape}
\begin{document}

\begin{landscape}
\begin{centering}
{\footnotesize
\begin{longtable}{cccccccc}

\caption{Termometría obtenida a partir del contenido de Ti en cristales de zircón.}\\\toprule
    \label{tab:tabla13}
\multicolumn{4}{c}{\textbf{Jamiltepec}} & \multicolumn{2}{c}{\textbf{Progreso}} & \multicolumn{2}{c}{\textbf{Río Grande}} \\

    \cmidrule(lr){1-4}
    \cmidrule(lr){5-6}
    \cmidrule(lr){7-8}
    \textbf{Spot/Muestra} & \textbf{T(°C)} & \textbf{Spot/Muestra} & \textbf{T(°C)} & \textbf{Spot/Muestra} & \textbf{T(°C)} & \textbf{Spot/Muestra} & \textbf{T(°C)} \\\midrule
    \endhead

        \textbf{HG-019A Zrn 01} & 749.4 & \textbf{HG-022 Zrn 03} & 992.3 & \textbf{HG-024F Zrn 01} & 769.5 & \textbf{HG-029 Zrn 02} & 720.6 \\
    \textbf{HG-019A Zrn 03} & 749.4 & \textbf{HG-022 Zrn 04} & 740.0 & \textbf{HG-024F Zrn 02} & 691.0 & \textbf{HG-029 Zrn 07} & 705.5 \\
    \textbf{HG-019A Zrn 04} & 722.9 & \textbf{HG-022 Zrn 06} & 722.9 & \textbf{HG-024F Zrn 03} & 713.3 & \textbf{HG-029 Zrn 12} & 747.6 \\
    \textbf{HG-019A Zrn 05} & 766.4 & \textbf{HG-022 Zrn 08} & 756.5 & \textbf{HG-024F Zrn 05} & 769.5 & \textbf{HG-029 Zrn 13} & 747.6 \\
    \textbf{HG-019A Zrn 06} & 745.7 & \textbf{HG-022 Zrn 09} & 727.4 & \textbf{HG-024F Zrn 06} & 726.8 & \textbf{HG-029 Zrn 14} & 889.4 \\
    \textbf{HG-019A Zrn 09} & 772.5 & \textbf{HG-022 Zrn 10} & 694.0 & \textbf{HG-024F Zrn 30} & 699.9 & \textbf{HG-029 Zrn 16} & 674.1 \\
    \textbf{HG-019A Zrn 16} & 807.6 & \textbf{HG-022 Zrn 11} & 738.0 & \textbf{HG-024F Zrn 31} & 669.1 & \textbf{HG-029 Zrn 8b} & 702.7 \\
    \textbf{HG-019A Zrn 17} & 741.9 & \textbf{HG-022 Zrn 12} & 749.4 & \textbf{HG-024F Zrn 32} & 686.2 & \textbf{HG-029 Zrn 26} & 786.7 \\
    \textbf{HG-019A Zrn 18} & 738.0 & \textbf{HG-022 Zrn 16} & 738.0 & \textbf{HG-024F Zrn 34} & 715.8 & \textbf{HG-029 Zrn 31} & 733.9 \\
    \textbf{HG-019A Zrn 20} & 751.2 & \textbf{HG-022 Zrn 17} & 764.8 & \textbf{HG-024F Zrn 40} & 713.3 & \textbf{HG-029 Zrn 39} & 738.0 \\
    \textbf{HG-019A Zrn 22} & 759.9 & \textbf{HG-022 Zrn 23} & 696.1 & \textbf{HG-024F Zrn 41} & 790.6 & -     & - \\
    \textbf{HG-019A Zrn 26} & 704.1 & \textbf{HG-022 Zrn 24} & 740.0 & -     & -     & -     & - \\
    \textbf{HG-019A Zrn 27} & 766.4 & \textbf{HG-022 Zrn 28} & 819.5 & -     & -     & -     & - \\
    \textbf{HG-019A Zrn 30} & 662.3 & \textbf{HG-022 Zrn 29} & 1023.3 & -     & -     & -     & - \\
    \textbf{HG-019A Zrn 33} & 731.8 & \textbf{HG-022 Zrn 30} & 725.2 & -     & -     & -     & - \\
    \textbf{HG-019A Zrn 36} & 804.1 & \textbf{HG-022 Zrn 33} & 682.2 & -     & -     & -     & - \\
    \textbf{HG-019A Zrn 38} & 769.5 & \textbf{HG-022 Zrn 35} & 743.8 & -     & -     & -     & - \\
    -     & -     & \textbf{HG-022 Zrn 36} & 681.9 & -     & -     & -     & - \\
    -     & -     & \textbf{HG-022 Zrn 37} & 730.5 & -     & -     & -     & - \\
    -     & -     & \textbf{HG-022 Zrn 40} & 727.4 & -     & -     & -     & - \\\bottomrule

 \end{longtable}
}
\end{centering}
\end{landscape}
\end{document}
```

Any help would be awesome. Thanks in advance.

Comment: I got errors with respect to the encoding too. Make sure that you use UTF-8 `\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}` instead of `\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}` and `\textdegree` for degree sign.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your label maybe interfering --mov it elsewhere

[image]

```
\documentclass[10pt,cleardoublepage=empty,twoside]{book}
\usepackage[a5paper]{geometry}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc} 
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{lscape}
\begin{document}

\begin{landscape}
\centering
{\footnotesize
\begin{longtable}{cccccccc}

\caption{Termometría obtenida a partir del contenido de Ti en cristales de zircón.}\\\toprule
%    \label{tab:tabla13}
\multicolumn{4}{c}{\textbf{Jamiltepec}} & \multicolumn{2}{c}{\textbf{Progreso}} & \multicolumn{2}{c}{\textbf{Río Grande}} \\

    \cmidrule(lr){1-4}
    \cmidrule(lr){5-6}
    \cmidrule(lr){7-8}
    \textbf{Spot/Muestra} & \textbf{T(°C)} & \textbf{Spot/Muestra} & \textbf{T(°C)} & \textbf{Spot/Muestra} & \textbf{T(°C)} & \textbf{Spot/Muestra} & \textbf{T(°C)} \\\midrule
    \endhead

        \textbf{HG-019A Zrn 01} & 749.4 & \textbf{HG-022 Zrn 03} & 992.3 & \textbf{HG-024F Zrn 01} & 769.5 & \textbf{HG-029 Zrn 02} & 720.6 \\
    \textbf{HG-019A Zrn 03} & 749.4 & \textbf{HG-022 Zrn 04} & 740.0 & \textbf{HG-024F Zrn 02} & 691.0 & \textbf{HG-029 Zrn 07} & 705.5 \\
    \textbf{HG-019A Zrn 04} & 722.9 & \textbf{HG-022 Zrn 06} & 722.9 & \textbf{HG-024F Zrn 03} & 713.3 & \textbf{HG-029 Zrn 12} & 747.6 \\
    \textbf{HG-019A Zrn 05} & 766.4 & \textbf{HG-022 Zrn 08} & 756.5 & \textbf{HG-024F Zrn 05} & 769.5 & \textbf{HG-029 Zrn 13} & 747.6 \\
    \textbf{HG-019A Zrn 06} & 745.7 & \textbf{HG-022 Zrn 09} & 727.4 & \textbf{HG-024F Zrn 06} & 726.8 & \textbf{HG-029 Zrn 14} & 889.4 \\
    \textbf{HG-019A Zrn 09} & 772.5 & \textbf{HG-022 Zrn 10} & 694.0 & \textbf{HG-024F Zrn 30} & 699.9 & \textbf{HG-029 Zrn 16} & 674.1 \\
    \textbf{HG-019A Zrn 16} & 807.6 & \textbf{HG-022 Zrn 11} & 738.0 & \textbf{HG-024F Zrn 31} & 669.1 & \textbf{HG-029 Zrn 8b} & 702.7 \\
    \textbf{HG-019A Zrn 17} & 741.9 & \textbf{HG-022 Zrn 12} & 749.4 & \textbf{HG-024F Zrn 32} & 686.2 & \textbf{HG-029 Zrn 26} & 786.7 \\
    \textbf{HG-019A Zrn 18} & 738.0 & \textbf{HG-022 Zrn 16} & 738.0 & \textbf{HG-024F Zrn 34} & 715.8 & \textbf{HG-029 Zrn 31} & 733.9 \\
    \textbf{HG-019A Zrn 20} & 751.2 & \textbf{HG-022 Zrn 17} & 764.8 & \textbf{HG-024F Zrn 40} & 713.3 & \textbf{HG-029 Zrn 39} & 738.0 \\
    \textbf{HG-019A Zrn 22} & 759.9 & \textbf{HG-022 Zrn 23} & 696.1 & \textbf{HG-024F Zrn 41} & 790.6 & -     & - \\
    \textbf{HG-019A Zrn 26} & 704.1 & \textbf{HG-022 Zrn 24} & 740.0 & -     & -     & -     & - \\
    \textbf{HG-019A Zrn 27} & 766.4 & \textbf{HG-022 Zrn 28} & 819.5 & -     & -     & -     & - \\
    \textbf{HG-019A Zrn 30} & 662.3 & \textbf{HG-022 Zrn 29} & 1023.3 & -     & -     & -     & - \\
    \textbf{HG-019A Zrn 33} & 731.8 & \textbf{HG-022 Zrn 30} & 725.2 & -     & -     & -     & - \\
    \textbf{HG-019A Zrn 36} & 804.1 & \textbf{HG-022 Zrn 33} & 682.2 & -     & -     & -     & - \\
    \textbf{HG-019A Zrn 38} & 769.5 & \textbf{HG-022 Zrn 35} & 743.8 & -     & -     & -     & - \\
    -     & -     & \textbf{HG-022 Zrn 36} & 681.9 & -     & -     & -     & - \\
    -     & -     & \textbf{HG-022 Zrn 37} & 730.5 & -     & -     & -     & - \\
    -     & -     & \textbf{HG-022 Zrn 40} & 727.4 & -     & -     & -     & - \\\bottomrule

 \end{longtable}
}

\end{landscape}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Yay! As simply as that! Thank you a lot!